# How to check if a string is a valid JSON in python

Tags: python, json, linux

I have a python script providing command line / output in console on remote linux.
I have another script which is reading this output on local machine. 
Output is in below format:

```
ABC: NEG
BCD: NEG
FGH: POS
{aa:bb:cc:dd:ee{"value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","configurationGroup":null,"name":"Configuration Deneme 3","description":null,"identity":"Configuration Deneme 3","version":0,"systemId":3,"active":true}}
```

notice last line is in json format, now I want to check which line is in json format of the output.
I tried

```
if "value" in line:
    json.loads(line)
```

it is not reading and even

> json.dumps(line)

not giving output ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [try except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) clause to check if a string is actually json:

```
import json
line = '<what you think is json>'
try:
    json_line = json.loads(line)
except ValueError:
    print("not a json")
```

In your above code the last line is not a valid JSON. You can use this tool [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to verify if your JSON is a valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It is saying no json object could be detected.

Comment: @Error_Coding Which is because your last line is not a valid JSON. Only this `{"value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","configurationGroup":null,"name":"Configuration Deneme 3","description":null,"identity":"Configuration Deneme 3","version":0,"systemId":3,"active":true}` segment in the last line is a valid JSON